# Write a function that returns an iterable object of all valid points 4-directionally adjacent to (x, y)

Tags: code-golf, geometry

A very common need in algorithms classes and computer science in general is to iterate 4-directionally over a grid or matrix (such as in BFS or DFS). This seems to often result in a lot of clunky and verbose code with a lot of arithmetic and comparisons within loops. I've seen many different approaches to this, but I can't shake the feeling that there's a more concise way to do this.

The challenge is to write a pure function that, given the width and height of a finite plane `n, m` originating at point `(0,0)`, and coordinates `(x,y)` that can represent any valid point within that plane, returns an iterable object of all points within the plane that are 4-directionally adjacent to `(x,y)`.

The goal is to define that function in as few bytes as possible.

Some examples to help illustrate valid input/output:

```
n = 5 (y-axis), m = 3 (x-axis) (zero-based)

matrix = [
    [A, B, C],
    [D, E, F],
    [G, H, I],
    [J, K, L],
    [M, N, O],
]

(x, y) => [valid iterable points]

E: (1, 1) => [(1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 1)]
A: (0, 0) => [(1, 0), (0, 1)]
L: (2, 3) => [(2, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3)]
N: (1, 4) => [(1, 3), (2, 4), (0, 4)]
```

```
n = 1 (y-axis), m = 1 (x-axis) (zero-based)

matrix = [
    [A],
]

(x, y) => [valid iterable points]

A: (0, 0) => []
```

```
n = 2 (y-axis), m = 1 (x-axis) (zero-based)

matrix = [
    [A],
    [B],
]

(x, y) => [valid iterable points]

A: (0, 0) => [(0, 1)]
B: (0, 1) => [(0, 0)]
```

And here's an example (this one in Python) of a function that satisfies the conditions:

```
def four_directions(x, y, n, m):
    valid_coordinates = []
    for xd, yd in [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]:
        nx, ny = x + xd, y + yd
        if 0 <= nx < m and 0 <= ny < n:
            valid_coordinates.append((nx, ny))
    return valid_coordinates
```

The example above defined a named function, but anonymous functions are also acceptable.

The inputs `n, m, x, y` are all unsigned 32-bit integers within the following ranges:

```
n > 0
m > 0
0 <= x < m
0 <= y < n
```

The output must take the form of an iterable (however your language of choice defines that) of (x, y) pairs.

*Additional clarifications:*

Complex numbers (and other representations/serializations) are OK as long as the consumer of the iterable can access `x` and `y` as integers knowing only their location.

Non-zero-based indexes are acceptable, but only if the language of choice is a non-zero-indexed language. If the language uses a mix of numbering systems, default to the numbering system of the data structure most commonly used to represent a matrix. If these are still all foreign concepts in the given language, any starting index is acceptable.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This challenge is pretty good by our standards, but there are a couple of things here that go against our style.  For one we much prefer challenges that do not restrict to a single language if possible.  It is much more fun when everyone can compete.  We also generally score code-golf in *bytes* as opposed to characters, they are the same for most purposes but there are a couple of cheaty things you can do if answers are scored in characters.  Hope you have fun here!

Comment: We're guaranteed that `(x,y)` itself is in the rectangle, right?

Comment: @xnor yes, `x, y` is guaranteed to be a point that exists

Comment: By default, CGCC allows full programs as well as functions as submissions. This helps allow languages that don't necessarily have a concept of functions to compete as well

Comment: @JoKing How would that work with a full program, considering the goal is an in-code iterable? Happy to accept that, I'm just not sure how the desired output would be defined.

Comment: An output would be to STDOUT, rather than a code object. This can generally be any output with clear delimiters so it is unambiguous and follow the default [Standard output formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: Is it allowed to represent coordinates as complex numbers rather than integer tuples?

Comment: Can we use 1-indexed coordinates?

Comment: @Joel Complex numbers (and other representations/serializations) are OK as long as the consumer of the iterable can access `x` and `y` as integers knowing only their location

Comment: @JoKing I would say yes, but only if the language of choice is a 1-indexed language. If the language has a mix of 0-based and 1-based indexing, default to the numbering system of the data structure most commonly used to represent a matrix.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```python
lambda m,n,x,y:[(x-1,y),(x+1,y)][~x:m-x]+[(x,y-1),(x,y+1)][~y:n-y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcuxCoMwFIXhvU/hGMkJeGO7BPokmsFSpIUmijjcu/jq0YBQMx34fs4s62eKNo3PPv2G8HoPVUAEQ1yn2BCkhmKd13cbu2DY66NADOUC0ZSLuGjEp3n5xrUaVYsHCFTfrtCgKcGiLYFw/8PxLy/2hLQD)

Lists the four neighbors, then uses list slicing to remove those that are out-of-bounds.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 71 bytes

```python
lambda m,n,x,y:[(k/n,k%n)for k in range(m*n)if(k/n-x)**2+(k%n-y)**2==1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcuxDsIgGATg3adgMQG8xkJ1MeFJbAeMogT525AO5emxTUyU7fLd3ZTn10i6ONOXt423u2URhAX5cuXhSAh7Em5MLDBPLFl6PniUJLzb2mYRUuoDX0dN3qIxaihT8jQzxzucoaDE7h9atDVodDUonH6w/uuL/kL5AA)

Instead of checking which of the four neighbors are in-bounds, we do it the slower way of checking all in-bounds points for those that are neighbors, that is have Euclidian distance exactly 1 from `(x,y)`. We also use the classic [div-mod trick to iterate over a grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41217/20260), saving the need to write two loops like `for i in range(m)for j in range(n)`.

I tried using complex arithmetic to write the distance condition, but it turned out longer to write `abs((k/n-x)*1j+k%n-y)==1`.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes

```python
lambda m,n,x,y:[(x+t/3,y+t%3-1)for t in-2,0,2,4if m>x+t/3>=0<y+t%3<=n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctBCsIwEEbhvaeYjdDSv5hM6qY0vYi6qEgwYKalZNGcPkoRNNuP95YUn7NwdvaaX1O4PyYKEGxI/aXamngySE08mlbXbl4pkpeWocDovKMw7slo1bBXg5VbXlYvkVxlcIaGrg//oKBKYJgSNLoffP5y4S/kNw)

Comment: Congrats on the 100k!

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 90 bytes

This uses a geometric approach: First we create an matrix of zeros of the desired size, and set a `1` to the desired location. Then we convolve with the kernel

```
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
```

which produces a new matrix of the same size with ones at the 4-neighbours of the original point. Then we `find()` the indices of the nonzero entries of this new matrix.

```matlab
function [i,j]=f(s,a,b);z=zeros(s);z(a,b)=1;[i,j]=find(conv2(z,(v=[1;-1;1])*v'<0,'same'));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLDgIhEAX3cwp3dJs2kVFXLSchLBCYBBPB2CMLLo@f6O6lqvJqWH1LYyzPEtZcy8ZmujqzgJCnC3I3PT2qgLwnfIjR/EtyiRBqaTN0gmas5p1m7XDb1HlPSvwtKUQeqcTp/2qPdHI00wF5ilnu8BU4Xg)

<sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>convolution is the key to success.</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup>

Comment: Indeed it is, no matter how small the font

Comment: Supbpbpbpberb technique ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>42</s> 37 bytes

```
pNorm[{##}-p]&~Array~#~Position~1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v@D9pIV@@UW50dXKyrW6BbFqdY5FRYmVdcp1AfnFmSWZ@Xl1hmr/A4oy80ogSuzSopVjo5WNYmPVHBwcqrmqq410jGp1qo11TGtrdYBcQx1DZK6xjgky1wjIgHPhqkEkKt8IZpgRjMtV@x8A)

Input `[{x,y}][{m,n}]`. 1-indexed, following Mathematica's convention.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

Boring approach.

```javascript
(h,w,x,y)=>[x&&[x-1,y],~x+w&&[x+1,y],y&&[x,y-1],++y-h&&[x,y]].filter(_=>_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@18jQ6dcp0KnUtPWLrpCTS26QtdQpzJWp65CuxzE0wbzKkFMnUpdw1gdbe1K3QwINzZWLy0zpyS1SCPe1i5e839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqmOgrGOgiEQaWpyYZMyACIcUkZAEocU0EATTc3/AA)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 74 bytes

Less boring but just as long. Takes input as `([h,w,x,y])`.

```javascript
a=>a.flatMap((_,d,[h,w,x,y])=>~(x+=--d%2)*~(y+=--d%2)&&x<w&y<h?[[x,y]]:[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLy0nscQ3sUBDI14nRSc6Q6dcp0KnMlbT1q5Oo0LbVlc3RdVIU6tOoxLGVlOrsClXq7TJsI@OBqmMtYqO1fyfnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RphFtqqNgrKNgCESxmppcWCUNgAinpBGQxCkJNNYEKPkfAA)

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 67 bytes

If all standard output methods were allowed, we could just print the valid coordinates with:

```javascript
(h,w,x,y)=>{for(;h--;)for(X=w;X--;)(x-X)**2+(y-h)**2^1||print(X,h)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvtfI0OnXKdCp1LT1q46Lb9IwzpDV9daE8SKsC23jgBxNCp0IzS1tIy0NSp1M0CMOMOamoKizLwSjQidDM3a/2kapjoKxjoKhkCkaa0AkdK05oKJGwARNnEjIIlNHGiOieZ/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13</s>  12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
2ḶṚƬNƬẎ+⁸%ƑƇ
```

A dyadic Link accepting a list of two (0-indexed) integers on the left, `[row, column]`, and two integers on the right, `[height, width]`, which yields a list of lists of integers, `[[adjacent_row_1, adjacent_column_1], ...]`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//MuG4tuG5msasTsas4bqOK@KBuCXGkcaH////WzQsMF3/WzUsM10)**

#### How?

```
2ḶṚƬNƬẎ+⁸%ƑƇ - Link: [row, column]; [height, width]   e.g. [3,2]; [5,3] (the "L" example)
2            - literal 2                                   2
 Ḷ           - lowered range                               [0,1]
   Ƭ         - collect up while distinct, applying:
  Ṛ          -   reverse                                   [[0,1],[1,0]]
     Ƭ       - collect up while distinct, applying:
    N        -   negate                                    [[[0,1],[1,0]],[[0,-1],[-1,0]]]
      Ẏ      - tighten                                     [[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[-1,0]]
        ⁸    - chain's left argument ([row, column])       [3,2]
       +     - add (vectorises)                            [[3,3],[4,2],[3,1],[2,2]]
           Ƈ - filter keep if:
          Ƒ  -   is invariant under:
         %   -     modulo ([height, width]) (vectorises)    [3,0] [4,2] [3,1] [2,2]
             - (...and [3,0] is not equal to [3,3] so ->)  [[4,2],[3,1],[2,2]]
```

Comment: You can replace `ḶṚƬ` with `Ṭ€`. `2ḶṚƬNƬẎ` returns `[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]]`, while `2Ṭ€NƬẎ` returns `[[1], [0, 1], [-1], [0, -1]]`, and, since the singletons are wrapped, `+` only vectorizes with the first element of `⁸` for those, so they act as though their second element is `0` (the additive identity). As a result, only the order of the output may change.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>56</s> 49 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to nwellnhof!*

```perl6
{grep 1>(*.reals Z/@^b).all>=0,($^a X+1,-1,i,-i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzq9KLVAwdBOQ0uvKDUxp1ghSt8hLklTLzEnx87WQEdDJS5RIULbUEfXUCdTRzdTs/Z/cWKlQpqGobZhpo6GsY6ppqY1F0TIQNsAXchI2xhdyFDbBC70HwA)

Removes the out of bounds elements by checking if when divided by the array bounds it is between 0 and 1. Takes input and output via complex numbers where the real part is the `x` coordinate and the imaginary is the `y`. You can extract these through the `.im` and `.re` functions.

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzq9KLVAwdBOQ0uvKDUxp1ghSt8hLklTLzEnx87WQEdDJS5RIULbUEfXUCdTRzdTs/Z/cWKlQpqGobZhpo6GsY6ppqY1F0TIQNsAXchI2xhdyFDbBC70HwA)

Comment: @nwellnhof Very nice! I'd build on it to do something like [this](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzq9KLVAQUNLryg1MadYISols8whLklTLy8/L1VHQyUuUSFC21BH11AnU0c3U7P2f3FipUKahqG2YaaOhrGOqaamNRdEyEDbAF3ISNsYXchQ2wQu9B8A), but `div` doesn't seem to work for `Num`s

Comment: `(*.reals>>.Int Zdiv@^b).none` or `(*.reals Z/@^b)>>.Int.none` would work but the Int-cast seems too costly.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>30</s></sup> <sup><s>29</s></sup> 28 bytes

```
(([+.@#~&,1=|@-)j./)~j./&i./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NTSitfUclOvUdAxtaxx0NbP09DXrgIRapp7@f00urtTkjHygcgOFNAVjBRMIV10dQhsCIRZhI6AQWPg/AA)

How:

- Turn the right hand `m` x `n` arg into a grid of complex numbers `j./&i./`
- Same for left arg (our point) `j./`
- Create a mask showing where the distance between our point and the grid is exactly 1 `1=|@-`
- Use that to filter the grid, after flattening both `#~&,`
- Turn the result back into real points `+.@`

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 62 bytes

Using [image: thecircle equation]

```
f m n a b = [(x,y)|x<-[0..m-1],y<-[0..n-1],(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2==1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxDoMgAEV3T/EHB0yFgLabnMRogtGmpoBGHSDx7kjTEaf/8pL/Pmr/TlqHYNRsITEuGaCnA28YWCgMUbbElb44XUNbzpihoiv9n@2PiaOq6KsH8XSIK6XoYmTdZnsgj6EaLwiIxHHwxFWob77PEC4)

Boring approach: 81 bytes

```
f m n x y=filter (\(x,y)->x>=0&&y>=0&&x<m&&y<n) [(x-1,y),(x+1,y),(x,y-1),(x,y+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 91 bytes

```cs
(a,b,x,y)=>new[]{(x+1,y),(x-1,y),(x,y+1),(x,y-1)}.Where(d=>((x,y)=d,p:x>=0&x<a&y>=0&y<b).p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY0/D4IwEMV3PwUTuYaDUNAF226auLk5GAf@lEiiDQGJbYyfvRY1Bhnuvbtf8t6VfVj2jd0OqmSNuuF0dhs1XGWXFxfJYASeEyKEV3vcQo4FajSECyXvx9MDdEDdiaDDr6MJ6MdDSp7R4Sw7CRUXAO9chW2mBY99zXLfjIthBYlaYteLfedeQQ0prpAiJeQfxRjPUYLpHFFcTpHrmQeTH7Iv)

Alternatively:

```cs
(a,b,x,y)=>new[]{(x+1,y),(x-1,y),(x,y+1),(x,y-1)}.Where(d=>((x,y)=d).Item1>=0&x<a&y>=0&y<b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY29D4IwEMV3/womcg0HoaCTbTdN2NwcjAMfJZBIBz5iG@PfXosagwz33t0vee/KISyH1h4nVbJWjbic7KCmTvZ5cZMMZuA5IUJ4tcct5FigRkO4UPJ@uT5AB9SdCDr8OpqAfjyk5BmdG9lLqLgAeOcqEmWj7Kjgsa9Z7pt5Mawgdr859e4V1JDiDilSQv5RjPEaJZiuEcXtErmedTD5IfsC)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
Ｊθη#ＦＩζＦＩε«Ｊικ¿№ＫＶ#⊞υ⟦ικ⟧»⎚Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY0xC8IwFITn5lc86vIexEHUqWO3DtJBXMQhlJSEpommfQ6Kvz2mIrrdcffddUbFLiiXUsPj9RjwJsFQJdpo/Yzlqsy6DxGwVtOMDyL4O53dUxRf0EoYcrmwfY4DZ7rVejgFf9A8Ku@RJCx7BC1PBlnCeUEumXmJ2mkV8ff7mWeiKqUN7GAL@7S@uzc) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes inputs in the order x, y, width, height. Explanation:

```
Ｊθη#
```

Print a `#` at the provided position.

```
ＦＩζＦＩε«
```

Loop over the given rectangle.

```
Ｊικ
```

Jump to the current position.

```
¿№ＫＶ#⊞υ⟦ικ⟧
```

If there's an adjacent `#` then save the position.

```
»⎚Ｉυ
```

Output the discovered positions at the end of the loop.

Boring answer:

```
ＦＩζＦＩε¿⁼¹⁺↔⁻ιＩθ↔⁻κＩηＩ⟦ικ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzmxuESjSlNTAcFLBfIy0xQ0XAtLE3OKNQx1FAJySos1HJOK83NKS1I1fDPzgNxMHQWw6kJNTU0dBTTJbKhkhiYYKAQUZeaVQEyPBmrMjtXUtP7/31DBRMFYwfS/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works by finding the adjacent positions mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xp`, 18 bytes

```
$ALaCGbFI1=$+:_ADc
```

Takes three command-line arguments: m, n, and a list containing x & y. [Replit!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's a similar program in Pip Classic with a header to simulate the `-x` flag: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@B9mlWgdZpUExMnW/1UcfRKd3ZPcPA1tVbQdnazidZP///@vW/Df@L/p/2hDa5NYAA)

#### Explanation

Generates a list of all points in the valid rectangle and filters for the ones that are one unit away from the given point.

```
$ALaCGbFI1=$+:_ADc
   aCGb             Generate a coordinate grid of a rows and b columns
$AL                 Fold on append-list: flatten once, giving a list of coord pairs
       FI           Filter on this function:
              _      The argument
               AD    Absolute difference (element-wise) with
                 c   The program's third argument
           $+:       The sum of the resulting pair
         1=          Must equal 1
```